# File transfer through socket - empty file

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I have a problem with transferring a file from server to client. After transfer finishes the file is created but its empty. Note that when I send it from client to server it works. Sometimes I also get EOF exceptions at long fileLength = dis.readLong() and String fileName = dis.readUTF().

Client:

```
private void sendFile(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    File file = new File(path);

    long length = file.length();
    dos.writeLong(length);

    String name = file.getName();
    dos.writeUTF(name);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    int theByte = 0;
    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) 
        bos.write(theByte);

    dos.close();
    bis.close();   

    displayMessage(MESSAGE_SENT);
}

private void getFile() throws IOException {     
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        long fileLength = dis.readLong();
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    int theByte = 0;
    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) 
        bos.write(theByte);

    bos.close();
    dis.close();
    displayMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOADED);
}
```

Server:

```
private void sendFile(String path) throws IOException {     
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    File file = new File(path);

    long length = file.length();
    dos.writeLong(length);

    String name = file.getName();
    dos.writeUTF(name);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    int theByte = 0;
    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) 
        bos.write(theByte);

    dos.close();
    bis.close();

    displayMessage(MESSAGE_SENT);
}

private void getFile() throws IOException {     
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    long fileLength = dis.readLong();
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) 
        bos.write(bis.read());

    bos.close();
    dis.close();
    displayMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOADED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in not flushing your output stream. Like so:

```
 int theByte = 0;
 while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) 
       bos.write(theByte);

    dos.flush();

    dos.close();
    bis.close();
```

Comment: doesnt dos.close() call flush()?

Comment: My bad. DataOutputStream is a subclass of FilterOutputStream and the API does say the close flushes as well. Sorry about that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close()

Comment: You do explicitly flush it in the client sendFile method however.

Comment: i was experimenting ;p and i didnt call dos.close() there - anyway i tested it and it doesnt work :(

Comment: When you step into your client code through the debugger, can you confirm that the data arrives and that it's not an issue with writing the file itself?

Comment: I've found that Apache Commons IOUtils can be handy for debugging the streams or printing their contents. Like this, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)